# Add a space between value in a cookie using PHP

Tags: php

Simple question but cant find the answer. I have this line of code:

```
setcookie($prodAmount, $pQuantity." ".$pOriginalQuan, time() + (86400 * 60), "/");
```

As you can see there is a space in the middle. however when I look at the cookie in the browser values are like this 3+4. how can I add space to the cookie so it looks like this 3 4.

Thanks

Comment: @Freed I tried that but it then the values become 34.

Comment: Try adding "%20" instead of " "

Comment: I deleted my comment about that; I didn't grasp the question which was `$pQuantity."".` so I was obviously wrong about it. @Luke

Comment: That is possibly because of [URL encoding](https://www.google.nl/search?q=url+encoding&oq=url+encoding).

Comment: It looks like it is url-encoded. That should not be a problem and you get the original value back when you read it again on the server. In javascript you can use `decodeURIComponent()` to get the orignal value.

Comment: The space is there. That `+` between `3` and `4` is a space encoded using the [early version of URL-encoding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type). Check the value of `$_COOKIE[$prodAmount]` on the next invocation of the PHP script. It should be `3 4`.

Comment: Ahh ok so even though there is a +,  it's just a space encoded :)

Answer (score 3):

A cookie value and name is a sequence of characters excluding semi-colon, comma and white space.

So you can't do that.

But you can use the function string urldecode ( string $str ) to get back you whitespace.

Comment: that's why it's url encoded with the set_cookie function